Background Service not working properly on Huawei (Specifically Huawei Nova 5T), Flutter developed application
I have a Taxi/Cab Flutter assistant application (works for both driver and users).
About App
App has two services, out of many others:

Location tracking service: On start of this service, the app gets the current location of the device every 10 seconds and sends to the server.

Taximeter service: On start (from the app) of this service, it also gets the location every few (2 or 3) seconds, calculates the fare and communicates with the server.


For the above two services to work, app's user has to give "Allow all the time" location access to the app, and also disable battery saving option for the app, to make the background service work.
Some Code
static startService() {
    _checkBatteryPermissions();
  }

  static stopService() {
    FlutterBackgroundService().invoke(_inputStopService);
  }

  static startTaximeter(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    FlutterBackgroundService().invoke(_inputStartTaximeter, data);
  }

  static stopTaximeter() {
    FlutterBackgroundService().invoke(_inputStopTaximeter);
  }

static _checkBatteryPermissions() async {
    ph.PermissionStatus status =
        await ph.Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.status;
    if (status == ph.PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _checkLocationPermissions();
    } else {
      ph.Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.request();
    }
  }

  //Check location permissions
  static _checkLocationPermissions() async {
    ph.PermissionStatus status = await ph.Permission.locationAlways.status;
    switch (status) {
      case ph.PermissionStatus.granted:
        _checkNotifyPermission();
        break;

      case ph.PermissionStatus.denied:
      case ph.PermissionStatus.restricted:
      case ph.PermissionStatus.limited:
      case ph.PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied:
        settingsLocationDialog();
        break;
    }
  }

Issue
The issue is that the aforementioned services does not work on Huawei devices. The service stops randomly, sometimes after 5 minutes, sometimes 30 minutes. But on most other android devices (out of the one's I tested), the app and the services work as expected.
Closure
I would like to know, if anyone else has faced this issue, or anything similar to this. Any suggestions, questions or solutions are welcome.
